# Shopify - Contact Form Country and Province

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm using the following code to add a country dropdown to a contact form based on the method [here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/country-option-tags)

```
<label for="ContactFormCountry" class="label--hidden">{{ 'contact.form.country' | t }}</label>
          <select required id="ContactFormCountry" name="contact[country]" data-default="{{form.country}}">{{ country_option_tags }}</select>
```

How would I go about making another dropdown menu allowing for choosing the province of the selected country?

Comment: I'll spend some more time a little bit later because I think I have an idea of how to do this - but in the mean time, check out the Shopify.CountryProvinceSelector here at https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/templates/customers-addresses. Shopify has built in functionality to search for the states/province of the selected country since its used in the edit account pages.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the pointer! I'm taking a look at it and want to know where an explanation of the function is (I don't know how to look at shopify_common.js).  How would you go about using it in a form outside of customer addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Now the tag is UPDATED

I Found this code from `Dawn theme` and it's works well

The form(demo)

```html
<div class="container" data-customer-addresses>    
    <div class="add-new-address">
      <div class="action text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary my-3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Add a new address</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse my-5" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="address-add">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
              <div id="AddAddress">
                <form action="#">
                  <div class="form-group my-3">
                    <div class="select">
                      <select
                        class="form-control"
                        id="AddressCountryNew"
                        name="address[country]"
                        data-default="{{ form.country }}"
                        autocomplete="country"
                      >
                        {{ all_country_option_tags }}
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="AddressProvinceContainerNew" style="display: none">
                    <div class="select">
                      <select
                        class="form-control"
                        id="AddressProvinceNew"
                        name="address[province]"
                        data-default="{{ form.province }}"
                        autocomplete="address-level1"
                      ></select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    typeof CustomerAddresses !== 'undefined' && new CustomerAddresses();
  });
</script>
```

Add This code on `theme.liquid` to get access every page.

```js
if (typeof window.Shopify == 'undefined') {
  window.Shopify = {};
}
Shopify.bind = function (fn, scope) {
  return function () {
    return fn.apply(scope, arguments);
  };
};

Shopify.addListener = function (target, eventName, callback) {
  target.addEventListener
    ? target.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false)
    : target.attachEvent('on' + eventName, callback);
};

Shopify.CountryProvinceSelector = function (country_domid, province_domid, options) {
  this.countryEl = document.getElementById(country_domid);
  this.provinceEl = document.getElementById(province_domid);
  this.provinceContainer = document.getElementById(options['hideElement'] || province_domid);

  Shopify.addListener(this.countryEl, 'change', Shopify.bind(this.countryHandler, this));

  this.initCountry();
  this.initProvince();
};

Shopify.CountryProvinceSelector.prototype = {
  initCountry: function () {
    var value = this.countryEl.getAttribute('data-default');
    Shopify.setSelectorByValue(this.countryEl, value);
    this.countryHandler();
  },

  initProvince: function () {
    var value = this.provinceEl.getAttribute('data-default');
    if (value && this.provinceEl.options.length > 0) {
      Shopify.setSelectorByValue(this.provinceEl, value);
    }
  },

  countryHandler: function (e) {
    var opt = this.countryEl.options[this.countryEl.selectedIndex];
    var raw = opt.getAttribute('data-provinces');
    var provinces = JSON.parse(raw);

    this.clearOptions(this.provinceEl);
    if (provinces && provinces.length == 0) {
      this.provinceContainer.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < provinces.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = provinces[i][0];
        opt.innerHTML = provinces[i][1];
        this.provinceEl.appendChild(opt);
      }

      this.provinceContainer.style.display = '';
    }
  },

  clearOptions: function (selector) {
    while (selector.firstChild) {
      selector.removeChild(selector.firstChild);
    }
  },

  setOptions: function (selector, values) {
    for (var i = 0, count = values.length; i < values.length; i++) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = values[i];
      opt.innerHTML = values[i];
      selector.appendChild(opt);
    }
  },
};
```

Now add this code, below of the above code according to your form

```js
const selectors = {
  customerAddresses: '[data-customer-addresses]',
  addressCountrySelect: '[data-address-country-select]',
  addressContainer: '[data-address]',
};

const attributes = {
  expanded: 'aria-expanded',
  confirmMessage: 'data-confirm-message',
};

class CustomerAddresses {
  constructor() {
    this.elements = this._getElements();
    if (Object.keys(this.elements).length === 0) return;
    this._setupCountries();
  }

  _getElements() {
    const container = document.querySelector(selectors.customerAddresses);
    return container
      ? {
          container,
          addressContainer: container.querySelector(selectors.addressContainer),
          countrySelects: container.querySelectorAll(selectors.addressCountrySelect),
        }
      : {};
  }

  _setupCountries() {
    if (Shopify && Shopify.CountryProvinceSelector) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-new
      new Shopify.CountryProvinceSelector('AddressCountryNew', 'AddressProvinceNew', {
        hideElement: 'AddressProvinceContainerNew',
      });
      this.elements.countrySelects.forEach((select) => {
        const formId = select.dataset.formId;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-new
        new Shopify.CountryProvinceSelector(`AddressCountry_${formId}`, `AddressProvince_${formId}`, {
          hideElement: `AddressProvinceContainer_${formId}`,
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```